# AngularJS : Update directive scope after successful HTTP request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am creating a directive to show success/failure message with slidedown effect depending upon response from http request in controller function.Below is the basic implementation.

```
<slidemsg msg="rmsg" type="rtype"></slidemsg>
```

My Directive :

```
app.directive('slidemsg',function(){
       return {restrict : 'EA',
              scope:{msg:'=',type:'='},
              templateUrl:'views/slideMsg.html',       
              controller:function($scope){
               console.log($scope.msg);
               console.log($scope.type);
             }}})
```

Http Request :

```
app.controller('empController',function($scope,employeeService,$window,$timeout){ 
  $scope.deleteUser=function(id)
 {
   var deleteUser = $window.confirm('Are you absolutely sure you want to delete?'); 
  if (deleteUser) { 
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(id).success(function(response){
       if(response.success)
        {   console.log('Deleted');
            $scope.rmsg="Successfully Deleted";
            $scope.rtype=true; 
         } 
}
 }});
```

When my page loads first time directive automatically gets called loads template and consoles rmsg & rtype as *undefined*.But after successful http request when i set rmsg and rtype in success function , directive doesn't get called neither consoles anything written in it.I also tried using $apply but it throws error [$rootScope:inprog]. 
Am i doing it the right way ?

Comment: Where do you do this request? in controller or where?

Comment: please, share whole part js code, where you request the data

Comment: I have updated my post with necessary code.

Comment: But as i see - it is another scope - you have 2 different scopes - one for directive and another in controller.

Comment: yes , you are right so i want to update directive scope from controller.Is it possible ? can we use watch in directive to get the updated value of msg & type ?

Answer (score 1):

The code should work.

Your `console.log`s should not, because they are called once when the directive initializes. So, like you said, at first the parameters are `undefined` and that's what you see in the console.

When you set your variables after the successful response, angular knows to update the directive. So if you have, for instance, a `<div ng-if="rtype">Test</div>` then it will show correctly. But consoles will not get recalled in your controller declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Well at last using watch solved my problem .
But still i didn't understand why angularjs didn't updated my directive scope from controller even after using two way binding. Below is the updated code .

```
app.directive('slidemsg',function(){
   return {restrict : 'EA',
          scope:{msg:'=',type:'='},
          templateUrl:'views/slideMsg.html',
          link:function(scope, element, attrs)
          {
           scope.$watch('msg',function(newmsgvalue,oldmsgvalue){},true);
           scope.$watch('type',function(newtypevalue,oldtypevalue){},true);  
          }
         }})
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller code is only executed during initialization. If you want code to be executed every time the directive's data changes (e.g. via the bidirectional data binding) then you can surround the code with a watch.

In your example:

```
controller:function($scope){
  $scope.$watch('msg', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log($scope.msg);
  });
}
```